# Why is my mongodb not connecting to my site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using the free tier of mongo and it won't connect to my site or api but it connects just fine with my bot. They all use the same connection string and method.

Connection code:

In file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoPath = process.env.MONGOPATH;

module.exports = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(mongoPath, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  return mongoose;
};
```

In index.js:

```
async function loadDatabase() {
const mongo = require('./src/database/database')
  await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
      try {
        console.log("Database Online.");
      } finally {
      }
    });
}
```

Full error: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster.

I have made a new db, made a new user, removed and added allow connection from anywhere.

Comment: `try { console.log("Database Online."); } finally {}` is a bit pointless. What is the purpose of `finally {}` At least you should catch the error and print the error message: `try {...} catch (err) { console.log(err.message) } finally {...}`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need insert or require your code in index.js file this code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoPath = process.env.MONGOPATH;

module.exports = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(mongoPath, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  return mongoose;
};
```